# Join contents of a list of text files sorted by sub-second modification date

Tags: unix, text

Suppose I have a few dozen text files with very close modification times (< 1 second from each other) and I want to join them in a single text file respecting chronological ordering (oldest file first). How can I do that? ls does not seem to be reliable (I get files sorted by the second, but my chronological intervals are sub-second). Stat and sort give me an accurate list:

`stat -c '%y -- %n' my_file_pattern | sort`

but how do I process the files then (presumably using cat)? I guess I could split the list with sed and a regex then pipe into xargs, but is there a simple method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using find instead, and so:

```
while read fil;
do 
   cat ${fil##*/};   
done <<< "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -printf "%Ts/%f\n" | sort -n)"
```

Use find to print all text files in the current directory formatted with the epoch format date, a "/" and the file name. Pipe the output through sort -n. Redirect the output into a while loop. Use ${fil##*/} to extract just the file name from the output of find and cat the file.